# Building mupdf-1.18.0 for Linux Mint 19.2 failed

Tags: linux, build, mupdf

I tried to build the MuPdf PDF reader program from mupdf-1.18.0-source package downloaded from https://mupdf.com/downloads/index.html on my Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon 4.2.4 (based on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic) system, but at the end it crashes.

There are several warnings for uninitialized and unused variables during the process, but at the very end:
install -d /usr/local/include/mupdf
install: cannot change permissions of ‘/usr/local/include/mupdf’: No such file or directory
Makefile:359: recipe for target 'install' failed

I even tried to "help out" the install and created the directory by hand, but after that more directories and more files were needed, and I bugged down file permission problems.

See full list below.

```html
<pre><font color="#8AE234"><b>zg@zg-HP-Laptop-14-cf0xxx</b></font>:<font color="#729FCF"><b>~/Downloads/mupdf-1.18.0-source</b></font>$ make prefix=/usr/local install
    CC build/release/source/fitz/archive.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/bbox-device.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/bidi-std.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/bidi.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/bitmap.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/buffer.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/color-fast.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/color-icc-create.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/color-lcms.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/colorspace.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/compress.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/compressed-buffer.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/context.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/crypt-aes.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/crypt-arc4.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/crypt-md5.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/crypt-sha2.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/device.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/directory.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/document-all.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/document.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-affine.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-blend.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-device.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-edge.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-edgebuffer.o
<b>source/fitz/draw-edgebuffer.c:</b> In function ‘<b>fz_gap_edgebuffer</b>’:
<b>source/fitz/draw-edgebuffer.c:435:30:</b> <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>warning: </b></font>‘<b>iy2</b>’ may be used uninitialized in this function [<font color="#AD7FA8"><b>-Wmaybe-uninitialized</b></font>]
    row = &amp;eb-&gt;table[eb-&gt;index<font color="#AD7FA8"><b>[</b></font>iy]];
                              <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>^</b></font>
<b>source/fitz/draw-edgebuffer.c:704:16:</b> <font color="#34E2E2"><b>note: </b></font>‘<b>iy2</b>’ was declared here
  int iy0, iy1, <font color="#34E2E2"><b>iy2</b></font>;
                <font color="#34E2E2"><b>^~~</b></font>
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-glyph.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-mesh.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-paint.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-path.o
<b>source/fitz/draw-path.c:</b> In function ‘<b>fz_dash_lineto</b>’:
<b>source/fitz/draw-path.c:755:14:</b> <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>warning: </b></font>‘<b>old_by</b>’ may be used uninitialized in this function [<font color="#AD7FA8"><b>-Wmaybe-uninitialized</b></font>]
  <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>s-&gt;seg[0].y = s-&gt;beg[0].y = y</b></font>;
  <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
<b>source/fitz/draw-path.c:1025:16:</b> <font color="#34E2E2"><b>note: </b></font>‘<b>old_by</b>’ was declared here
  float old_bx, <font color="#34E2E2"><b>old_by</b></font>;
                <font color="#34E2E2"><b>^~~~~~</b></font>
<b>source/fitz/draw-path.c:754:14:</b> <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>warning: </b></font>‘<b>old_bx</b>’ may be used uninitialized in this function [<font color="#AD7FA8"><b>-Wmaybe-uninitialized</b></font>]
  <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>s-&gt;seg[0].x = s-&gt;beg[0].x = x</b></font>;
  <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
<b>source/fitz/draw-path.c:1025:8:</b> <font color="#34E2E2"><b>note: </b></font>‘<b>old_bx</b>’ was declared here
  float <font color="#34E2E2"><b>old_bx</b></font>, old_by;
        <font color="#34E2E2"><b>^~~~~~</b></font>
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-rasterize.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-scale-simple.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/draw-unpack.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/encode-basic.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/encode-fax.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/encodings.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/error.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/filter-basic.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/filter-dct.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/filter-fax.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/filter-flate.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/filter-jbig2.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/filter-leech.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/filter-lzw.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/filter-predict.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/filter-sgi.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/filter-thunder.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/font.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/ftoa.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/geometry.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/getopt.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/glyph.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/halftone.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/harfbuzz.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/hash.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/image.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/jmemcust.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/link.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/list-device.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/load-bmp.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/load-gif.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/load-jbig2.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/load-jpeg.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/load-jpx.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/load-jxr.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/load-png.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/load-pnm.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/load-tiff.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/log.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/memento.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/memory.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/noto.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/ocr-device.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/outline.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/output-cbz.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/output-pcl.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/output-pclm.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/output-pdfocr.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/output-png.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/output-pnm.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/output-ps.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/output-psd.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/output-pwg.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/output-svg.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/output.o
<b>source/fitz/output.c:</b> In function ‘<b>file_truncate</b>’:
<b>source/fitz/output.c:130:2:</b> <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>warning: </b></font>ignoring return value of ‘<b>ftruncate</b>’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [<font color="#AD7FA8"><b>-Wunused-result</b></font>]
  <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>ftruncate(fileno(file), ftell(file))</b></font>;
  <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
    CC build/release/source/fitz/path.o
<b>source/fitz/path.c:</b> In function ‘<b>fz_walk_path</b>’:
<b>source/fitz/path.c:686:5:</b> <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>warning: </b></font>‘<b>y</b>’ may be used uninitialized in this function [<font color="#AD7FA8"><b>-Wmaybe-uninitialized</b></font>]
     <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>proc-&gt;curveto(ctx, arg,</b></font>
     <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
 <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>      x,</b></font>
       <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>~~</b></font>
 <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>      y,</b></font>
       <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>~~</b></font>
 <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>      coords[k],</b></font>
       <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
 <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>      coords[k+1],</b></font>
       <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>~~~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
 <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>      coords[k+2],</b></font>
       <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>~~~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
 <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>      coords[k+3])</b></font>;
       <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>~~~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
<b>source/fitz/path.c:686:5:</b> <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>warning: </b></font>‘<b>x</b>’ may be used uninitialized in this function [<font color="#AD7FA8"><b>-Wmaybe-uninitialized</b></font>]
    CC build/release/source/fitz/pixmap.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/pool.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/printf.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/random.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/separation.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/shade.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/stext-device.o
<b>source/fitz/stext-device.c:</b> In function ‘<b>fz_add_stext_char_imp</b>’:
<b>source/fitz/stext-device.c:304:6:</b> <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>warning: </b></font>variable ‘<b>rtl</b>’ set but not used [<font color="#AD7FA8"><b>-Wunused-but-set-variable</b></font>]
  int <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>rtl</b></font> = 0;
      <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>^~~</b></font>
    CC build/release/source/fitz/stext-output.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/stext-search.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/store.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/stream-open.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/stream-read.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/string.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/strtof.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/svg-device.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/test-device.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/text.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/time.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/trace-device.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/track-usage.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/transition.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/tree.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/ucdn.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/untar.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/unzip.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/util.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/warp.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/writer.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/xml.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/xmltext-device.o
    CC build/release/source/fitz/zip.o
    CXX build/release/source/fitz/tessocr.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-annot.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-appearance.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-clean-file.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-clean.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-cmap-load.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-cmap-parse.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-cmap.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-colorspace.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-crypt.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-device.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-event.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-font-add.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-font.o
    CC build/release/source/pdf/pdf-form.o

    Here I had to delete some code because it was too long to submit
   
    OBJCOPY build/release/resources/fonts/sil/CharisSIL-Bold.cff.o
    OBJCOPY build/release/resources/fonts/sil/CharisSIL-BoldItalic.cff.o
    OBJCOPY build/release/resources/fonts/sil/CharisSIL-Italic.cff.o
    OBJCOPY build/release/resources/fonts/sil/CharisSIL.cff.o
    AR build/release/libmupdf.a
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/base/ftbase.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/base/ftbbox.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/base/ftbitmap.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/base/ftdebug.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/base/ftgasp.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/base/ftglyph.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/base/ftinit.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/base/ftstroke.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/base/ftsynth.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/base/ftsystem.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/base/fttype1.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/cff/cff.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/cid/type1cid.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/psaux/psaux.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/pshinter/pshinter.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/psnames/psnames.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/raster/raster.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/sfnt/sfnt.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/smooth/smooth.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/truetype/truetype.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freetype/src/type1/type1.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/gumbo-parser/src/attribute.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/gumbo-parser/src/char_ref.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/gumbo-parser/src/error.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/gumbo-parser/src/parser.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/gumbo-parser/src/string_buffer.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/gumbo-parser/src/string_piece.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/gumbo-parser/src/tag.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/gumbo-parser/src/tokenizer.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/gumbo-parser/src/utf8.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/gumbo-parser/src/util.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/gumbo-parser/src/vector.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-aat-layout.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-aat-map.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-blob.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-buffer.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-buffer-serialize.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-common.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-face.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-fallback-shape.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-font.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ft.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-map.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-number.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-cff1-table.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-cff2-table.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-color.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-face.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-font.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-layout.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-map.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-math.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-meta.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-metrics.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-name.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-arabic.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-default.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-hangul.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-hebrew.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-indic.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-indic-table.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-khmer.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-myanmar.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-thai.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-use.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-use-table.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-complex-vowel-constraints.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-fallback.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-shape-normalize.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-tag.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ot-var.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-set.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-shape.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-shape-plan.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-shaper.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-static.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-subset.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-subset-cff1.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-subset-cff2.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-subset-cff-common.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-subset-input.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-subset-plan.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-ucd.o
    CXX build/release/thirdparty/harfbuzz/src/hb-unicode.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jaricom.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jcomapi.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdapimin.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdapistd.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdarith.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdatadst.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdatasrc.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdcoefct.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdcolor.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jddctmgr.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdhuff.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdinput.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdmainct.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdmarker.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdmaster.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdmerge.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdpostct.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdsample.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdtrans.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jerror.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jfdctflt.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jfdctfst.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jfdctint.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jidctflt.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jidctfst.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jidctint.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jmemmgr.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jquant1.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jquant2.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/libjpeg/jutils.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsalpha.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmscam02.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmscgats.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmscnvrt.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmserr.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsgamma.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsgmt.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmshalf.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsintrp.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsio0.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsio1.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmslut.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsmd5.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsmtrx.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsnamed.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsopt.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmspack.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmspcs.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsplugin.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsps2.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmssamp.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmssm.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmstypes.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsvirt.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmswtpnt.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/lcms2/src/cmsxform.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/mujs/one.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/zlib/adler32.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/zlib/compress.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/zlib/crc32.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/zlib/deflate.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/zlib/inffast.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/zlib/inflate.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/zlib/inftrees.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/zlib/trees.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/zlib/uncompr.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/zlib/zutil.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_arith.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_arith_iaid.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_arith_int.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_generic.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_halftone.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_huffman.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_hufftab.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_image.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_mmr.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_page.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_refinement.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_segment.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_symbol_dict.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/jbig2dec/jbig2_text.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/bio.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/cio.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/dwt.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/event.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/function_list.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/image.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/invert.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/j2k.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/jp2.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/mct.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/mqc.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/openjpeg.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/pi.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/sparse_array.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/t1.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/t2.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/tcd.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/tgt.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2/thread.o
    AR build/release/libmupdf-third.a
    CC build/release/source/tools/mutool.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/muconvert.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/mudraw.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/murun.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/mutrace.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/cmapdump.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/pdfclean.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/pdfcreate.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/pdfextract.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/pdfinfo.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/pdfmerge.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/pdfpages.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/pdfposter.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/pdfshow.o
    CC build/release/source/tools/pdfsign.o
    CC build/release/source/helpers/pkcs7/pkcs7-check.o
    CC build/release/source/helpers/pkcs7/pkcs7-openssl.o
    AR build/release/libmupdf-pkcs7.a
    CC build/release/source/helpers/mu-threads/mu-threads.o
    AR build/release/libmupdf-threads.a
    LINK build/release/mutool
    CC build/release/source/tools/muraster.o
    LINK build/release/muraster
    CC build/release/platform/gl/gl-annotate.o
    CC build/release/platform/gl/gl-file.o
    CC build/release/platform/gl/gl-font.o
    CC build/release/platform/gl/gl-form.o
    CC build/release/platform/gl/gl-input.o
    CC build/release/platform/gl/gl-main.o
<b>platform/gl/gl-main.c:</b> In function ‘<b>open_browser</b>’:
<b>platform/gl/gl-main.c:81:3:</b> <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>warning: </b></font>ignoring return value of ‘<b>getcwd</b>’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [<font color="#AD7FA8"><b>-Wunused-result</b></font>]
   <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>getcwd(buf_cwd, sizeof buf_cwd)</b></font>;
   <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
    CC build/release/platform/gl/gl-ui.o
    CC build/release/platform/gl/gl-win32.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_callbacks.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_cursor.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_display.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_ext.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_font.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_font_data.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_gamemode.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_geometry.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_gl2.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_init.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_input_devices.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_joystick.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_main.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_menu.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_misc.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_overlay.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_spaceball.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_state.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_stroke_mono_roman.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_stroke_roman.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_structure.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_teapot.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_videoresize.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/fg_window.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_cursor_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_display_x11_glx.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_ext_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_gamemode_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_glutfont_definitions_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_init_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_input_devices_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_joystick_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_main_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_menu_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_spaceball_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_state_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_state_x11_glx.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_structure_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_window_x11.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_window_x11_glx.o
    CC build/release/thirdparty/freeglut/src/x11/fg_xinput_x11.o
    AR build/release/libfreeglut.a
    LINK build/release/mupdf-gl
    CC build/release/platform/x11/pdfapp.o
<b>platform/x11/pdfapp.c:</b> In function ‘<b>pdfapp_gotouri</b>’:
<b>platform/x11/pdfapp.c:1112:3:</b> <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>warning: </b></font>ignoring return value of ‘<b>getcwd</b>’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [<font color="#AD7FA8"><b>-Wunused-result</b></font>]
   <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>getcwd(buf_cwd, sizeof buf_cwd)</b></font>;
   <font color="#AD7FA8"><b>^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
    CC build/release/platform/x11/x11_main.o
    CC build/release/platform/x11/x11_image.o
    LINK build/release/mupdf-x11
install -d /usr/local/include/mupdf
install: cannot change permissions of ‘/usr/local/include/mupdf’: No such file or directory
Makefile:359: recipe for target &apos;install&apos; failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
</pre>
```

Comment: This was great! I used sudo and I think it is a success, ran like a breeze (I could send the Terminal window screenshot and the Makefile "batch file" to see if everything ran off of it and if was it OK). However I don't know how to verify the install as I can't find a point where I can start the MuPdf program from (sorry, I fairly new in Linux). What and where should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

It’s frustrating that compiling C programs throws up so many errors.  Lots of confusion to figure out what’s really going on.

I suspect your issue is that installing into /use/local requires root permissions.

You can try

```
su - root && make install
```

Or

```
sudo make install
```

sudo is generally held to be the superior way to gain root permissions.

Alternatively, you can change you prefix to a path you have write permissions to:

E.g.

```
make prefix=~/mydir install && make install
```

Hope that helps. Good luck!